# How to render a video component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render a video component, which is called as a result of an input action from another component. I have tried several ready-made packages installed through npm install. but none seem to be working for me. So, I'm of the opinion that the problem is with my own code :

```
    *// this component receives a prop based on the user's action*
        import React from 'react';
        import ShowMovie from 'ShowMovie'

        class MoviePick extends React. Component{

        render(){
        return(
        <div>
        {props.movie==="Startrek"? <ShowMovie/> : <span>only startrek is vailable}</span>
        }
    </div>
        );
        }
}


        *// this component shows the movie*
        import React from 'react'
        import VideoPlayer from 'react-simple-video-player';

        const ShowMovie = () => (
          <VideoPlayer
            url="/startrek.mp4"
            poster="/myPoster.png"
            width={400}
            height={300}
            autoplay
          />
        );

        export default ShowMovie ;
```

Comment: You're missing a closing div-tag in the MoviePick component. That might be the issue.

Comment: I don't think its the closing div tag, just added it, still not rendering

Comment: @8SINS try adding a public url

Answer (score 0):

For videos i usually use [react-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player)

```
<ReactPlayer url='https://video URL / video file' playing />
```